# SFML 2.0 - Window closes immediately after showing up

Tags: c++, codeblocks, sfml

Window immediately closes after showing up, even though it should wait for close event.
main.h:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "window.h"
int main()
{
    window::window mainwindow;
    mainwindow.createwindow(800, 600);
    while(mainwindow.window.pollEvent(mainwindow.events)){
        if (mainwindow.events.type == sf::Event::Closed){
            mainwindow.window.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

window.h:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace window{
class window{
    public:
        sf::Window window;
        sf::Event events;
        void createwindow(int resx, int resy){
            window.create(sf::VideoMode(resx, resy), "MainWindow", sf::Style::Default);
            }
        };
}
```

The code is based on this SFML tutorial : `https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/window-window.php` 
I am using SMFL 2-2.5.1-23.83 with IDE being code::blocks 20.03.
Thanks for all help

Comment: Maybe because `pollEvent` returns `false` because event queue is empty. In docs `while (window.pollEvent(event))` is in `while (window.isOpen())`. It keeps the window open even no events in queue.

Comment: Swapping `mainwindow.events.type == sf::Event::Closed` for `mainwindow.window.isOpen()` did solve the problem. Thank You EOF